# Map function and referring to variables inside template literals

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I'm trying to use map function to create buttons with template literal but the element `levelCurriculumInfo` is not accessed and the string literal of template is displayed in the UI instead of the value.
I'm not sure if I'm using the quotes right.
 How can I make this work?

```js
`<tr>
  <td class="clc-${concept.conceptCode}">
    ${getSortedLevelCurriculumList(concept)}.map(levelCurriculumInfo, index) { if(levelCurriculumInfo.levelName != levelCurriculumInfo.currName) {
    <span id="clc-tag-" + levelCurriculumInfo.clcId + " class="level label label-success " > levelCurriculumInfo.levelName </span>
    <span id="clc-tag-curr- " + levelCurriculumInfo.clcId + " class="curriculum">- levelCurriculumInfo.currName</span>
    } else {
    <span class="na" style="font-weight: 700;">No Subject/Grade Tagged To This Concept</span> } }
  </td>
</tr>`
```

Comment: `map(levelCurriculumInfo, index) {` should be `map(function(levelCurriculumInfo, index) {` or `map((levelCurriculumInfo, index) => {`. Not sure if there are other syntax errors but given this one, there might be. I'd suggest not writing so much code in a template literal - write it outside and use regular tools like syntax highlighting and (even better) linters to check its validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the quotes and the template literals correctly

Remove the quotes and use ${} to wrap the variables

You can nest template literals like I do here

I use a ternary to not have to add `{ if () ... else }` to the map

The map needs to be attached the the array and the resulting array has to be .join("") or you will get commas in the cells

```js
`<tr>
  <td class="clc-${concept.conceptCode}">
    ${getSortedLevelCurriculumList(concept)
      .map(levelCurriculumInfo, index) => (levelCurriculumInfo.levelName === levelCurriculumInfo.currName) ?
        `<span class="na" style="font-weight: 700;">No Subject/Grade Tagged To This Concept</span>`
      : 
        `<span id="clc-tag-${levelCurriculumInfo.clcId}" class="level label label-success"> ${levelCurriculumInfo.levelName}</span><span id="clc-tag-curr-${levelCurriculumInfo.clcId}" class="curriculum">- ${levelCurriculumInfo.currName}</span>`)
      .join("") }
  </td>
</tr>`
```

Comment: "*use a ternary since you cannot have else in template literals*" - you can have `if/else` in the `map` callback function though. What's missing is the `return` statements.

Comment: @Bergi Correct, I updated my description